# How to add new user in VMC viewer?

Tags: redhat

I want to login from remote[Windows] machine with a new linux user using VMC viewer.
With root user currently I can login in to the linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

pls Edit this file /etc/sysconfig/vncservers for adding ahis in vncserver for installing ahis application 
VNCSERVERS="2:root"
VNCSERVERS="3:ahis"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x768"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1024x768"